# Oracle query I have to fetch the records based on department(admin, user, emp) and respective role(1,2,3,4,5) from employee table

Tags: oracle

There are two tables 1. employess (column emp_name, emp_dept, emp_address ) 2. department (dept, role)

I have to fetch the records from employee table 
based on department(admin, user, emp) and respective role(1,2,3,4,5) from employee and department table.
If employee is admin then records with role 1 and 3 should be fetched if user then only records with role 5.

Please help me to write the query.
Following is the query which I tried:

select emp_name, emp_dept, 
(select role from department d where d.dept= e.emp_dept) role, emp_address
from employee e
where role IN (case emp_dept 
                 when 'admin'
                 then('1','3')
                 when 'user'
                 then ('5')
                 when 'emp'
                 then('4')
                 end
                 )

Answer (score 0):

Could be good to start with a  **Users** table , where you will store all users independently if they are admin or employee . After that try to write a draft of **E/R model** , to make us understand what you need .